# Syntax errors after updated to Angular 4 and "rxjs": "^5.0.1",

Tags: angular, rxjs

I had to update to Angular 4 from 2 to be able to use some third party controls. I had to also upgrade rxjs package.

I used to have lines such as

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

which now cause syntax errors. Where can I now find map and catch?

Or how do I get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first change this line

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

with this

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

if not work try update rxjs.

I hope that it helps you

Answer (score 0):

The RxJS v5 [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#installation-and-usage) suggests to import it like this:

```
// import observable
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// import operators
import 'rxjs/add/observable/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Stay up-to-date with:

```
npm install rxjs@latest --save
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I still get:

// import observable
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// import operators
import 'rxjs/add/observable/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/add/observable/map.js as "rxjs/add/observable/map" from http://localhost:3000/app/flowsheet.service.js

Any thoughts?

Comment: my package.json has

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4"
  }